# BeagleBone -> HTML -> C++ communication

Tags: c++, html, websocket, beagleboneblack

I've successfully configured my beaglebone to host a website, now I'd like to enable the website viewer to communicate with a C++ program running on the beaglebone as well. I have done some reading and have a few ideas, but I don't have a solid conceptualization of the pieces that I'll need so I am looking for some advice.

I'd like two way communications, and I would like low latency, and limited restrictions on the type of data I tx/rx.

I've done some reading on WebSockets, which look to provide what I want, but I am struggling to understand how I get a WebSocket running in my C++ program, and if there's a middle man (WebSocket server?).

Please let me know if you have any advice or suggested reading for me as I work through this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in [AutobahnCpp](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnCpp/#show-me-some-code). That can be used to do the following architecture:

`Your C++ Component <--WAMP-over-RawSocket--> WAMP Router <-- WAMP-over-WebSocket --> Browser`

[WAMP](http://wamp.ws/) allows bidirectional real-time messaging: remote procedure calls and publish & subscribe.

E.g. you could visualize data coming from C++ in real-time in a browser. Or you could call into C++ from JavaScript in the browser.

Here are some pointers:

- https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnCpp/
- http://crossbar.io/docs/Getting-started-with-Cplusplus/
- https://github.com/crossbario/crossbar/blob/master/crossbar/crossbar/templates/hello/cpp/hello.cpp
- https://github.com/crossbario/crossbar/blob/master/crossbar/crossbar/templates/hello/cpp/web/index.html

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I'm currently looking into implementing this.  

To make sure my understanding is correct, I'd host a wamp router on the BBB(likely with CrossBar.io) I'd then use AutoBahnCpp in my c++ program to communicate with the router, and AutoBahnJS in my html code to communicate with the router.  

Is that correct?  

I've found the google group for WAMP, do you have any additional suggested resources? As you're aware, the WAMP name has a few different web related meanings, so it hasn't been simple to find good resources for it.  

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I know, the name "WAMP" is overloaded. Here are some tips for searching stuff on the Web: http://wamp.ws/faq/#naming. Two resources I'd recommend: http://wamp.ws/why/ and http://tavendo.com/blog/post/is-crossbar-the-future-of-python-web-apps/ (this is somewhat Python focused, but translates to other langs as well).

Regarding your understanding: yes, exactly. This is one option. Router and C++ component on BBB. The HTML/JS is just files served via HTTP (can also be done from Crossbar). Another option would be: C++ component on BBB, but Router somewhere in the cloud. Zero code change.

Comment: Unfortunately my debian install has GCC 4.6 which seems to be causing compiler errors with AutoBahnCpp, any advice? http://pastebin.com/s3KcXyHZ I may update my GCC, but it's not a solution that I love... Let me know if you think my errors may lie elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: My tip would be: try your exact code first on a desktop Linux (like Ubuntu 14) with clang. If it works, gcc is letting you down. If that is the case (gcc): sorry, I have no time fiddling with gcc.

Comment: I've made some progress by cross compiling everything with GCC4.8.2 and targeting the beaglebone. Unfortunately I've run into my next hurdle, any ideas would be appreciated. I am getting the following error when I try to run "crossbar start"  ApplicationError: ApplicationError('wamp.error.runtime_error', args = (u'could not load WAMP-MsgPack serializer',), kwargs = {})

Comment: @fooOnYou to install crossbar with msgpack support (which is _optional_), do `pip install crossbar[msgpack]`. to install crossbar with all optional things do `pip install crossbar[tls,msgpack,manhole,system]`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I've gotten the examples working, and now I am tweaking to suit my needs. I apprecaite your help through the process!